# How to prevent npm from installing demo/sample/example/test code for a package?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there a way to have npm not install certain elements of a package? Like tests or example/demo code?

For example, in my *test-api* project, a package that I'm using has a dependency called *jmespath*:

```
user@hostname MINGW64 ~/Projects/test-api/node_modules/jmespath (develop) 
$ ll 
total 109 
drwxr-xr-x 1 user group     0 May 15 00:16 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x 1 user group     0 May 15 00:17 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   126 Apr 25  2014 .eslintrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group    13 Apr 10  2014 .npmignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group    71 Jul 22  2015 .travis.yml 
drwxr-xr-x 1 user group     0 May 15 00:16 artifacts/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   932 Feb 29  2016 BASELINE
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   443 Jul 22  2015 bower.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user group   270 Feb 15  2016 g.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   855 Mar 25  2016 Gruntfile.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  3130 Apr 25  2014 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   105 Apr 28  2014 james.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 58310 Mar 25  2016 jmespath.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user group   535 Feb 13  2016 jp.js*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  4645 Feb 29  2016 l.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   559 Jul 22  2015 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  1802 May 15 00:16 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  1229 Mar 25  2016 perf.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  2011 Jul 22  2015 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   151 Feb 13  2016 reservedWords.json 
drwxr-xr-x 1 user group     0 May 15 00:16 test/
```

Here *index.html* is a demo app and test directory contains tests. If I do not want these in the *node_modules* directory, is there a way to exclude them during *npm install*?

Comment: Nope, you basically get the git repository. When you later compile your project, these files, will not be included, I'm guessing only `jmespath.js` in this case, will be used in your project.

Comment: The short answer is _"No"_. However, if you're sure your project doesn't need those files to work successfully and your main issue is that you don't want them present after someone installs your package. Consider adding a [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script in your `test-api` project's _package.json_ file to delete the files using e.g. [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf). For instance: `"postinstall": "rimraf node_modules/some-folder/*"`. Of course the files will still be installed when someone installs your project but they will be deleted upon completion.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation RobC. Postinstall script with rifraf sounds like a good option and I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

No, the whole git repository of the dependency package is downloaded and then the package's dependencies are installed too from their package.json, all this information is stored in your package-lock.json.